# Second Moment of shifted Geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I know that the PGF of a shifted geometric distribution is $\frac{zp}{1-z(1-p)}$ where $z$ is the observed value of the random variable $Z$ and $0<p<1$. I am facing difficulties finding $G^{''}_Z(z)|_{z=1}$  in order to get the variance given as
$G^{''}_Z(z)|_{z=1} + G^{'}_Z(z)|_{z=1} - (G^{'}_Z(z)|_{z=1})^2 = \frac{1-p}{p^2}$.

A detailed expression of $ G^{''}_Z(z)|_{z=1}$ will help.

Comment: I don't think your probability generating function is correct.  Try again.

Comment: @heropup. The pgf is correct

Comment: It is now correct because someone else fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply deriving the PGF and applying the formula for the variance.

Let's set $q=1-p$ to semplify the notation:

$$G'=\frac{p[1-zq]+zpq}{(1-zq)^2}=\frac{p}{(1-zq)^2}=p(1-zq)^{-2}$$

$$G''=2pq(1-zq)^{-3}$$

Now simply sustituting you get

$$G'']_{z=1}+G']_{z=1}-(G']_{z=1})^2=\frac{2pq}{p^3}+\frac{p}{p^2}-(\frac{p}{p^2})^2=\frac{2(1-p)}{p^2}+\frac{p}{p^2}-\frac{1}{p^2}=\frac{2-2p+p-1}{p^2}=\frac{1-p}{p^2}$$

as known also by other ways.

Usually to get the simple moments Moment Generating Function is used, say

$$M_{z}(t)=\frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}$$

instead of Probability Generating Function...but the result is the same

Comment: Setting $q=1-p$ makes life easier. Without $q$ life becomes messy, a situation I found myself tryin to get Var $Z$.